# Как связать классы двух элементов?

Tags: vue.js

Даны два элемента:

```
<input id="title" v-bind:class="{success:ifSuccess}">
<button v-bind:class="checkTitle()" id="btn">Добавить</button>
```

Vue:

```
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#title',
  data: {
    ifSuccess: false
  }
})

var app2 = new Vue({
  el: '#btn',
  methods: {
    checkTitle: function () {
      if(app2.ifSuccess=='success') return 'ready'
    }
  }
})
```

Класс `success` присваивается полю при успешной его валидации. Не получается с данным кодом связать, кнопке не присваивается класс `ready`. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможные варианты работы с "классами" подробно расписаны по [ссылке](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad)

Приведу пример с модификацией вашего кода, может это вам поможет. Допустим  `ifSuccess` является результатом валидации, тогда ссылаясь на его значение можно сформировать `class` для элементов `DOM`.

PS: Пример меняет классы кнопки и поля ввода при условии, что поле ввода содержит хотя бы один символ.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: {
    ifSuccess: false,
    title: ''
  },
  methods: {
    validateInput: function() {
      this.ifSuccess = this.title != '';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  outline: none
}

input,
button {
  padding: 5px
}

.success {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: green
}

.ready:after {
  content: ' [class=ready]'
}
.disabled:after {
  content: ' [class=disabled]'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app2">
  <input v-model="title" :class="{success:ifSuccess}" @keyup="validateInput">
  <button :disabled="!ifSuccess" :class="[{ready:ifSuccess},{disabled:!ifSuccess}]" id="btn">Добавить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96998/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Answer (score 1):

Что касается валидации через `Jquery Validate`. Это плохоая идея. Вам не стоит использовать библиотеки которые модифицируют `DOM` вместе с Vue и прочими подобными фраемворками. Одно из главных приемуществ Vue, в том что он сам следит за состоянием `DOM` и производит изменения максимально эфективно. Обращаясь к DOM из JQuery Вы не только сводите это приемущество на нет, но и нарушаете алгоритмы работы Vue.

В Vue есть готовые библиотеки для валидации, но если форма не очень сложная то всегда можно обойтись маленьким сниппетом. Вот пример:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        errors: [],
        email: '',
        password: ''
    },
    methods: {
     // Простой валидатор для почты проверяет что перед сиволом at (@) есть другие символы, а так же что в домене есть хотя бы одна точка.
        // a+b@biz.co.uk будет валидным
  // @biz, a@biz, a.biz.co не будут
        emailValidator (string) {
            return !/^[\S]+@[\w]+\.[\w.]+$/i.test(string);
        },

  // Простой валидатор пароля, проверят что введено не менее 6 любых символов.
        passwordValidator (string) {
            return !/^\S{6,}$/.test(string);
        },
        
        // функция вызывается при submit'е формы
        submit (e) {
         // isValid проводит валидацию формы, если нет ошибок то можно отправлять содержимое формы на сервер.
            if (this.isValid()) {
                alert("Форма валидна!");
            }
        },

        isValid (e) {
         // обнуляем ошибки предыдущей валидации.
            this.errors = [];

   // проверяем что в поле email что-то введено, иначе выкидываем ошибку.
            if (!this.email) {
                this.errors.push("Нужно ввести email!");
            } 
            // валидируем введенные даные emailValidator вернет true если валдмция не пройдена, или false если пройдена.
            else if (this.emailValidator(this.email)) {
                this.errors.push("Email не вылидный!");
            }

            if (!this.password) {
                this.errors.push("Нужно ввести пароль!");
            } else if (this.passwordValidator(this.password)) {
                this.errors.push("Пароль должен содержать минимум 6 символов");
            }

   // если ошибок нет, возвращаем true
            return this.errors.length === 0;
        }
    }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E !important;
  padding: 20px !important;
  font-family: Helvetica !important;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

ul {
    margin: 0
}

label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">

        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" v-show="errors.length !== 0">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="error in errors" :key="error">{{ error }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" v-model="email" id="email" name="email" 
                   class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" v-model="password" name="password"
                   class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### Немного подредактировал код Николая.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        title: ''
    },
    computed: {
     isValid () {
         return this.title !== ''
        }
    }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

* {
  outline: none
}

input,
button {
  padding: 5px
}

.success {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: green
}

.ready:after {
  content: ' [class=ready]'
}
.disabled:after {
  content: ' [class=disabled]'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input v-model="title" :class="{ success: isValid }">
    <button :disabled="!isValid" :class="[(isValid ? 'ready' : 'disabled')]" id="btn">Добавить</button>
</div>
```